# Change WooCommerce phone number link on emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need WooCommerce email phone number to open Whatsapp on click. Currently when I click on it, it opens option to dial the number, I want to change this to open to Whatsapp.

So far I've found is (last option).

```
<?php
    function wc_make_phone_clickable( $phone ) {
        $number = trim( preg_replace( '/[^\d|\+]/', '', $phone ) );
        return $number ? '<a href="tel:' . esc_attr( $number ) . '">' . esc_html( $phone ) . '</a>' : '';
    }
?>
```

I will really like not to touch the plugin since upon updates this will be lost.

Whatsapp link  https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX, but phone field on checkout page does not have area code, so i will need to add this to

Comment: Woocommerce has templates that you can copy to your own theme and make any changes there - so you don't overwrite core files. Look in the woocommerce plugin files for `templates > email` and copy the one you need to your theme.

Comment: by copying the email template i can see what you say, but there are only hook and i don't know how will i achive what i need from here

Comment: You can remove the hook. You can do whatever you want with that, since it's your template.

Comment: can you please give me an example of how it should be, i want everything elseto remain the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet.

```
function change_email_customer_details_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    if ( isset( $fields[ 'billing_phone' ] ) ) {
        $phone                               = $fields[ 'billing_phone' ][ 'value' ];
        $number                              = trim( preg_replace( '/[^\d|\+]/', '', $phone ) );
        $fields[ 'billing_phone' ][ 'value' ]    = $number ? '<a href="https://wa.me/' . esc_attr( $number ) . '">' . esc_html( $phone ) . '</a>' : '';
        ;
    }
    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'change_email_customer_details_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: i did, and changed the html line  $fields[ 'billing_phone' ][ 'value' ]    = $number ? '<a href="https://wa.me/' . esc_attr( $number ) . '">' . esc_html( $phone ) . '</a>' : '';        but it  not openning whatsapp

Comment: $fields[ 'billing_phone' ][ 'value' ]    = $number ? '<a href="https://wa.me/507xxxxx">' . esc_html( $phone ) . '</a>' : '';      but it still opens the dial phone option

Comment: Use https://wa.me/<number> where the <number> is a full phone number in international format.

Comment: i did, but it seems like is not overriding, cause no matter i i change it stills showing the phone as tel html. i even remove the <a href="tel:' and it stills show the html tel